# Connecting to virtual Android Wear (avd) with Android M Preview 3

Tags: android, adb, wear-os, android-virtual-device, nexus-5

I'm trying to connect to virtual Android Wearable (Android 5.1.1) with my phone. (Nexus 5, Android M Preview 3)

```
gabor@gabor-U430p:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
0934deb30ddf309d    device
gabor@gabor-U430p:~$ adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
gabor@gabor-U430p:~$ adb -d forward --list
0934deb30ddf309d tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

In my phone, I didn't find "connect to emulator"
 button. If I touch "Connect" button, nothing happen.

[My Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ota2e.png)

Documentation what I read: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

```
Android Wearable App: 1.3.0.2236842
Android Play Services: 8.1.15_(2250156-438)
Android Build Number: MPA44l (Nexus 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Android Wear version (1.3.0.2236842) working.